# How do I create an anchor link to jump from the bottom of a div to the top of that div?

Tags: html, wordpress, hyperlink, anchor

I have a menu on my [website's homepage](http://www.estheticianschooling.com/) that is made of a scrolling div that contains all 50 states and the District of Columbia. Each state is a link to a different page.

My question is: How do I create an anchor link with the link text "Back to Top" at the end of the list of states that will automatically scroll back up to the top of the list, so mobile users don't have to use their finger to slide back up to the top of the menu once they get to the bottom? Is there a way to do this using HTML5 without any javascript?

I tried doing an anchor link inside the div like this:

```
<p><div id="" style="overflow: scroll; height: 200px; margin-left: 1em;"></p>

<strong id="menutop">Select Your State:</strong>

Alabama

Alaska

.

.

.

Wyoming

<a href="#menutop">Back to Top</a>

</div>
```

Obviously, I didn't list all the states there, but you get the idea. Anyway, that didn't work. Which is why I'm here now.

Comment: There is some javascript on your site that is intercepting the click and scrolling to the top of the homepage. I copied your code and it works by itself. Also, your html is invalid. You should remove the `<p></p>` tags at the top since it is wrapping just the opening `<div>` tag.

Comment: Thanks, but, unfortunately, I tried that, and it doesn't work because the anchor link (Back to Top) has to be INSIDE the div because the div is the container that holds the states. I tried exactly what you said to do, (except the Back to Top is inside the div instead of outside of it), and when I clicked "Back to Top" the whole webpage moved up a little bit. I only need to div element to scroll up, not the whole webpage.

Comment: Sorry, I made that other comment before I saw your code. The code was hidden because it wasn't formatted as code. Can you read my newest comment?

Comment: Oh. Those <p> tags aren't in the actual code where my div is. I just put those <p> tags in my post on here because it wasn't displaying my example like it is displayed on my webpage.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using the Divi theme since my website is a WordPress site. I'm not sure if there is some javascript built in that is causing the problem you described. Any suggestions on what to do?

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like the theme is adding its own functionality to links with "#". Maybe there is a setting in the theme to disable that feature. If not, you would have to remove the event callback with javascript.

Comment: Okay. I guess I'll have to try the Divi support team. Thanks for your help.